# GAE - Task Queue stored task bytes quota reached

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue, quota

We had an errant task load up the Task Queue in GAE, and it filled up the available 'stored task bytes'. We have resolved the issue and purged the task queues, but it has been a few hours and the space has not been reclaimed.

Is there any way to force the task queue to recognize that space is now available and let tasks resume?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: As an update to this, the space was finally freed up after about 4 hours and tasks can resume.

Comment: [How resources are replenished](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#How_Resources_are_Replenished) says `Daily quotas are replenished daily at midnight Pacific time.` But that doesn't match the clearing time you observed...

Comment: Hi, as the question is solved, could you please make an answer to it and accept it so it can help better other users in the community?

Comment: Check your queue to see if Google has applied a low "enforced rate" to the task queue (this is shown on the console).  Google did this to me when I had a similar task queue issue.  I didn't realize it and it crippled my app for about a week.

Comment: will do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to take about 4 hours for the Task Queue 'stored task bytes' to get reset so more tasks could get processed. Hopefully this helps someone in the future so they don't have to sit and refresh their dashboard over and over the entire time... :)